# Kotlin Jetpack Compose, Card, change color on click

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I cant get the `Card` in the `LazyColumn` to check if the number is in val `guestNumbers` and then change the color on the `Card`.

But the numbers in val `guestNumbers` changes on startup.

Is the `Card` the right stuff to use or should i use buttons?

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {

            val guestNumbers = rememberSaveable {
                mutableStateOf(mutableSetOf<Int>(10,11,2,22))
            }

            NumberGuessingGameTheme {

                Scaffold(
                    topBar = {
                        TopAppBar {

                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    ) {

                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .weight(4f)
                                .background(color = Color.LightGray)
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = "1F",
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption
                            )
                        }

                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .weight(1f)
                                .background(color = Color.LightGray)
                        ) {
                            LazyColumn {
                                items(1000 + 1) {
                                    Card(modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxSize()
                                        .padding(5.dp)
                                        //.background(if ("$it".toInt() !in guestNumbers.value) Color.Green else Color.Red)
                                        .clickable {
                                            guestNumbers.value.add("$it".toInt())
                                            Log.d("Tag", "${guestNumbers.value}")
                                        },
                                        elevation = 10.dp,
                                        backgroundColor = if ("$it".toInt() in guestNumbers.value) Color.Red else Color.LightGray
                                    ) {
                                        Text(text = "$it", fontSize = 28.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mutableStateOf` cannot track changes of the underlaying object. It can only trigger recomposition when you replace its value with an other object.

You can store an immutable set, create a modifiable copy to change it, and set the new value to your mutable state. This will create a new object.

```
var guestNumbers by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(setOf(10,11,2,22))
}

Button({
    val mutableSet = guestNumbers.toMutableSet()
    mutableSet.add(if (Random.nextBoolean()) 2 else Random.nextInt())
    guestNumbers = mutableSet.toSet()
}) {
    Text(guestNumbers.toString())
}
```

Note, that if you'll face same problem with a list, you gonna need to call `.toImmutableList()`, because `.toList()` is only erasing the type and not actually creating a new object if called on a mutable list.